# 404 error in custom module frontname

Tags: magento-1.9, controllers, router, frontend-error

I installed `ExtetionsStore_ContactConstant` from the `GitHub`. After installed I tried to go to frontcontroller url. but I am getting `404 error`.

Here is my `config.xml` file code.

```
 <frontend>
        <routers>
            <extensions_store_constantcontact>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>ExtensionsStore_ConstantContact</module>
                    <frontName>constantcontact</frontName>
                </args>
            </extensions_store_constantcontact>
        </routers>       
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <extensions_store_constantcontact module="ExtensionsStore_ConstantContact">
                    <file>extensions_store/constantcontact.xml</file>
                </extensions_store_constantcontact>
            </updates>
        </layout>     
    </frontend>
```

Here is my `controller` file `FormController.php`

```
<?php

/**
 * ConstantContact form controller
 *
 * @category    ExtensionsStore
 * @package     ExtensionsStore_ConstantContact
 * @author      Extensions Store <admin@extensions-store.com>
 */
class ExtensionsStore_ConstantContact_FormController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action 
{
    public function indexAction() {
        echo 'Hello';exit;
    }
    protected function _initLayout()
    {
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');   

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get singleton model
     * @return ExtensionsStore_ConstantContact_Model_Constantcontact
     */
    protected function _getModel()
    {
        $model = Mage::getSingleton('extensions_store_constantcontact/constantcontact');

        return $model;
    }

    /**
     * Subscribe page
     */
    public function subscribeAction()
    {
        if ($this->_getModel()->isReady()){

            $this->loadLayout()->_initLayout()->renderLayout();

        } else {

            $this->norouteAction();
        }
    }

    /**
     *  Subscribe form action 
     * 
     */
    public function subscribePostAction()
    {
        if (!$this->_validateFormKey()) {
            $this->_redirect('*/*/subscribe');
            return;
        }

        if ($this->_getModel()->isReady() && $this->getRequest()->isPost()) {

            $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();

            $result = $this->_getModel()->addUpdateContact($data);

            if ($result['error'] === false){

                Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('extensions_store_constantcontact')->__('We have received your information. Thank you for subscribing.'));

            } else {

                Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError(Mage::helper('extensions_store_constantcontact')->__('There was an error processing your request. Please, try again later'));
            }

        } else {

            Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError(Mage::helper('extensions_store_constantcontact')->__('There was an error processing your request. Please, try again later'));
        }

        $this->_redirect('*/*/subscribe');

    } 

}
```

also in module's `readme` file:

```
/constantcontact/form/subscribe URL for the use this extension...
```

can anyone tell me to solve this error.

Comment: You are getting 404 error because you may not have enabled the extension from the settings.

Comment: I enabled the module from the settings. but not fill all the data. does it cause problem?

Comment: Yes, since the extension requires Access key, access token, access secret, rate limit per day etc. to be configured, if you don't provide these values, the extension may not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extension requires to be configured from the backend first before you start using it for the frontend.

There are many settings, without which the extension will not work.

The controller's subscribe action has the following code:

```
if ($this->_getModel()->isReady()){
    $this->loadLayout()->_initLayout()->renderLayout();
} else {
    $this->norouteAction();
}
```

which means if the model **isReady()** function returns false, then Magento will redirect to the 404 error page.

So, you need to first all the required settings to make the extension start working.

Comment: i enabled the extension and fill all the data but still goes to 404 on `constantcontact ` , but when i goes with `/constantcontact/form/subscribe` then i see result. but can you tell me why am I not able to see result using `constantcontact ` URL.

Comment: @H_Parekh, since the controller file is FormController.php, you will be able to see the result on /constantcontact/form URL for your index action.